# How can we upload video to a specific user account in using youtube api in android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, youtube-api, google-oauth, android-youtube-api

I am creating an application in that I want application users to upload videos to my application's youtube page in place of their own user account.

I have tried/studied below mentioned methods to achieve above requirement.

1. Service account --> As per my investigation we cannot use service account to access youtube API.
2. Hard-coding user id and pwd in my application and call youtube APIto get the token. I have used the guidelines in [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#Authentication) url.

Below is my observations/investigations.

A. I am able to successfully receive token from google

B. In my subsequent call with received token I am getting 401 response code.

1. Use oauth 2 protocol for token request. In this I am not sure how I can pass user id and password to get the access token.

If anyone has any solution to above mentioned problem then please share.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this; if you do decide to do this, it's not something YouTube can offer support for.

The reasons why this is a bad idea are outlined in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff for your reply.. We will follow youtube API guidelines.